# if i have two objects of same class and i use setattr method of pyhton for setting value in one object what will happen to another object

Tags: python, oop

my understanding about classes is that your objects should have same attributes
so i am confused about this that how my second object would behave **Here is my code for understanding object oriented programming**

```
class Emmploy:
    ecount = 0
    
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        Emmploy.ecount = Emmploy.ecount+1
        
    def disemploy(self):
        print("name of employ:",self.name,"age of employ:",self.age)
    def empcount():
        print("total employs are:",Emmploy.ecount)


emp1 = Emmploy("zahid",35)
emp2 = Emmploy("hassan",34)
emp1.disemploy()
emp2.disemploy()
Emmploy.empcount()
val = str(hasattr(emp1,'salary'))
print(val)   
val = str(setattr(emp1,'salary',3500))
print(val)
print(emp1.salary)
print(emp2.salary)`
```

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Two different objects can have totally different values as their attributes as they are two different things

So,

emp1 can have a salary of 3500 and a name like Joe

whereas,

emp2 can have a salary of 4000 and a name like Doe

Hope this provides some clarity

Comment: I think what's confusing him is that `emp2` doesn't have a `salary` attribute at all.

Comment: in my __init__ method i'm not passing salary

Comment: Your object should follow the arguments present in the class, this makes your code more robust, clean and easier to understand

Comment: yes you are right @Barmar and i'm setting the attribute salary through "setattr" method

Answer (score 0):

Python is a dynamic language, like PHP and JavaScript. Classes don't have fixed attributes, each object in the class only has the attributes that are explicitly assigned to it. It's not like C++, where you have to declare all the class attributes and methods when defining the class.

Common attribute are normally assigned in the `__init__()` method, but you can add and remove attributes in each object later. You don't need to use `setattr()`, you can write:

```
emp1.salary = 3500
```

`setattr()` and `getattr()` are mainly used when the attribute name is in a variable.

Since you never assigned a `salary` attribute to `emp2`, you'll get an error when you try to access `emp2.salary`.

Although the language allows this flexibility, you don't have to use it. For ease of understanding, it's a good idea to assign default values to all attributes in the `__init__()` method.

Comment: yes ! you are very right and reached at root cause i switched from c++ to python and learning python. thanks @Barmar